# close my ports programatically using netbeans

Tags: java, bluetooth, jssc

I am using server program to connect with arduino board I am using hc-05 bluetooth in my arduino board so that it is wireless and then scratch program will open which will display some output.I am using serial port communication where I am displaying COM ports and it displays well.I will select one com port from the combobox and when i press the connect button scratch file will open. This works fine for the first time. When I again run my application my program throws an exception "`gnu.io.nosuchportexception`" or "`gnu.io.portinuseexception`" I don't know how to solve this issue. I am using the following code in server program.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

import gnu.io.CommPort;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import gnu.io.NoSuchPortException;
import gnu.io.PortInUseException;
import gnu.io.UnsupportedCommOperationException;

import org.firmata.Firmata;

public class A4S {
private static int[] firmataPinModes=   {Firmata.INPUT,Firmata.OUTPUT,Firmata.ANALOG,Firmata.PWM,Firmata.SERVO };
    private static String[] a4sPinModes={"Digital%20Input",  "Digital%20Output","Analog%20Input","Analog%20Output%28PWM%29","Servo"};

private static final int PORT = 12345; // set to your extension's port number
private static int volume = 8; // replace with your extension's data, if any

private static InputStream sockIn;
private static OutputStream sockOut;

private static SerialPort serialPort;
private static Firmata arduino;

private static SerialReader reader;

public static class SerialReader implements SerialPortEventListener {
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent e) {
        try {
            while (serialPort.getInputStream().available() > 0) {
                int n = serialPort.getInputStream().read();
                //System.out.println(">" + n);
                arduino.processInput(n);
            }
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.err.println(err);
        }
    }
}

public static class FirmataWriter implements Firmata.Writer {
    public void write(int val) {
        try {
            //System.out.println("<" + val);
            serialPort.getOutputStream().write(val);
        } catch (IOException err) {
            System.err.println(err);
        }
    }
}

//public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    public A4S(String args[]) throws IOException
    {

    try {
                    System.out.println(args[0]);
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.err.println("Please specify serial port on command line.");
            return;
        }
        //CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM3");

                    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(args[0]);
        CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open("A4S",2000);

        if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
        {
            serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(57600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            arduino = new Firmata(new FirmataWriter());
            reader = new SerialReader();

            serialPort.addEventListener(reader);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000); // let bootloader timeout
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
                            {
                               throw new RuntimeException("sorry",e) ; //added line
                            }

            arduino.init();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }

    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println("HTTPExtensionExample helper app started on " + addr.toString());

    ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    while (true) {
        Socket sock = serverSock.accept();
        sockIn = sock.getInputStream();
        sockOut = sock.getOutputStream();
        try {
            handleRequest();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            sendResponse("unknown server error");
        }
        sock.close();
                   // serverSock.close();
    }
}

private static void handleRequest() throws IOException {
    String httpBuf = "";
    int i;

    // read data until the first HTTP header line is complete (i.e. a '\n' is seen)
    while ((i = httpBuf.indexOf('\n')) < 0) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[5000];
        int bytes_read = sockIn.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
        if (bytes_read < 0) {
            System.out.println("Socket closed; no HTTP header.");
            return;
        }
        httpBuf += new String(Arrays.copyOf(buf, bytes_read));
    }

    String header = httpBuf.substring(0, i);
    if (header.indexOf("GET ") != 0) {
        System.out.println("This server only handles HTTP GET requests.");
        return;
    }
    i = header.indexOf("HTTP/1");
    if (i < 0) {
        System.out.println("Bad HTTP GET header.");
        return;
    }
    header = header.substring(5, i - 1);
    if (header.equals("favicon.ico")) return; // igore browser favicon.ico requests
    else if (header.equals("crossdomain.xml")) sendPolicyFile();
    else if (header.length() == 0) doHelp();
    else doCommand(header);
}

private static void sendPolicyFile() {
    // Send a Flash null-teriminated cross-domain policy file.
    String policyFile =
        "<cross-domain-policy>\n" +
        "  <allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"" + PORT + "\"/>\n" +
        "</cross-domain-policy>\n\0";
    sendResponse(policyFile);
}

private static void sendResponse(String s) {
    String crlf = "\r\n";
    String httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + crlf;
    httpResponse += "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" + crlf;
    httpResponse += "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" + crlf;
    httpResponse += crlf;
    httpResponse += s + crlf;
    try {
        byte[] outBuf = httpResponse.getBytes();
        sockOut.write(outBuf, 0, outBuf.length);
    } catch (Exception ignored) { }
}

private static void doCommand(String cmdAndArgs) {
    // Essential: handle commands understood by this server
    String response = "okay";
    String[] parts = cmdAndArgs.split("/");
    String cmd = parts[0];

    //System.out.print(cmdAndArgs);
    if (cmd.equals("pinOutput")) {
        arduino.pinMode(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), Firmata.OUTPUT);
    } else if (cmd.equals("pinInput")) {
        arduino.pinMode(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), Firmata.INPUT);
    } else if (cmd.equals("pinHigh")) {
        arduino.digitalWrite(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), Firmata.HIGH);
    } else if (cmd.equals("pinLow")) {
        arduino.digitalWrite(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), Firmata.LOW);
    } else if (cmd.equals("pinMode")) {
        arduino.pinMode(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), getFirmataPinMode(parts[2]) );
    } else if (cmd.equals("digitalWrite")) 
            {
               // if(parts[1].equals(""))
        arduino.digitalWrite(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), "high".equals(parts[2]) ? Firmata.HIGH : Firmata.LOW);
    } else if (cmd.equals("analogWrite"))
            {

               if(parts[1].equals("Speaker"))//addedline
               {
                 int value=3;
                 arduino.analogWrite(value, Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));//addedline
               }
                else if(parts[1].equals("Left_RED"))//addedline
               {
                int value=4;
                 arduino.analogWrite(value, Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));//addedline
               }
               else if(parts[1].equals("Left_GREEN"))//addedline
               {
                  int value=5;
                  arduino.analogWrite(value, Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));//addedline
               }
               else if(parts[1].equals("Left_BLUE"))//addedline
               {
                  int value=6;
                  arduino.analogWrite(value, Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));//addedline
               }
               else if(parts[1].equals("Right_RED"))//addedline
               {
                  int value=7;
                  arduino.analogWrite(value, Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));//addedline
               }
               else if(parts[1].equals("Right_GREEN"))//addedline
               {
                   int value=8;
                   arduino.analogWrite(value, Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));//addedline
               }
               else if(parts[1].equals("Right_BLUE"))//addedline
               {
                 int value=9;
                 arduino.analogWrite(value, Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));//addedline
               }
                else if(parts[1].equals("Left_Motor_Forward"))//addedline
               {
                  int value=10;
                  arduino.analogWrite(value, Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));//addedline
               }
                else if(parts[1].equals("Left_Motor_Backward"))//addedline
               {
                  int value=11;
                  arduino.analogWrite(value, Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));//addedline
               }
                else if(parts[1].equals("Right_Motor_Forward"))//addedline
               {
                  int value=12;
                  arduino.analogWrite(value, Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));//addedline
               }
                else if (parts[1].equals("Right_Motor_Backward"))//addedline
               {
                  int value=13;
                  arduino.analogWrite(value, Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));//addedline
               }

    }
            else if (cmd.equals("servoWrite")) {
        arduino.servoWrite(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));
    } else if (cmd.equals("poll")) {
        // set response to a collection of sensor, value pairs, one pair per line
        // in this example there is only one sensor, "volume"
        //response = "volume " + volume + "\n";
        response = "";
for (int i = 2; i <= 13; i++) {
        response += "digitalRead/" + i + " " + (arduino.digitalRead(i) == Firmata.HIGH ? "true" : "false") + "\n";
        }

                       for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)     //defaultline                                      
                       {response += "analogRead/" + i + " " + (arduino.analogRead(i)) + "\n";} //defaultline */
} else {
        response = "unknown command: " + cmd;
    }
    System.out.println(" " + response);
    sendResponse(response);
}
private static int getFirmataPinMode(String a4sPinMode){
    int idx=0;
    while (idx < a4sPinModes.length-1 && (! a4sPinMode.equals(a4sPinModes[idx]))) idx++;
    if (! a4sPinMode.equals(a4sPinModes[idx]) ) idx=0;
    return firmataPinModes[idx];
}
private static void doHelp() {
    // Optional: return a list of commands understood by this server
    String help = "HTTP Extension Example Server<br><br>";
    sendResponse(help);
}

}
```

and following code in Listing the ports.

```
package listserialports;

import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;
import jssc.SerialPortList;

/*
 * Get list of ports available on this particular computer
 */
public class ListSerialPorts
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

        }

        public Vector LoadComPorts()
        {
                   int totalElements;
                    CommPortIdentifier portId;
                    Enumeration en =  CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
                    Vector listData = new Vector(8);
                    // Walk through the list of port identifiers and, if it
                           // is a serial port, add its name to the list.
                    while (en.hasMoreElements())
                    {
                                portId = (CommPortIdentifier) en.nextElement();
                                if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
                                {
                                            listData.addElement(portId.getName());
                                }

                                           //
                                            //  listData.addElement("COM30"); //ADDEDLINE
                    }

                   //   listData.addElement("COM29"); //ADDEDLINE

                    totalElements = listData.size();

                    //Iterate through the vector
                    for (int index = 0; index < totalElements; index ++)
                    {
                                System.out.println(listData.get(index));
                    }

                    return listData;
        }

     public Vector LoadComPorts2() //addedline
        {
               Vector listData = new Vector(8);

                String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();

                for (String port : portNames)
                {
                   listData.add(port);
                }


               return listData;
}


}
```

So kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: can any one help me out to solve this issue :(

Comment: is there anyone who can help me to solve this issue as this is issue is still creating problems.

Comment: Maybe you need to close the port before using it again? can we see your relevant code?

Comment: ya u can use. yes i need to close the port before using it again

Comment: i feel that since the ports which i already used is opened once i run my application and does not close for some time so i think i should close the ports before i run my application again

Comment: Yea you must, and if its running on windows, it has some know issues with ports left open...

Comment: whats the solution for this ? any code to close the ports

Comment: Just call close().. and try closing the streams too.

Comment: Can you please explain the code in more detail ?